# Alternative proof of "Every linear mapping on a finite dimensional space is continuous”

Tags: functional-analysis

Here is my question:

Suppose that $T:X\to Y$ is linear, where $X$ and $Y$ are normed linear spaces, and $X$ is finite dimensional. Define $\|\cdot\|_\beta$ on $X$ by

$$\|x\|_\beta=max\{\|x\|_X,\|Tx\|_Y\}$$

1) Check that $\|\cdot\|_\beta$ is a norm on $X$

2) Argue that $T:(X,\|\cdot\|_\beta)\to Y$ is continuous, and hense that so is $T:X\to Y$ in the original norm on $X$.

---

Here is what I have (I am looking for feedback on the two proofs) :

1) As $\|\cdot\|_X$ and $\|\cdot\|_Y$ are norms, we know that $\|x\|_X\geq 0$ and $\|Tx\|_Y\geq 0$, as well as $\|x\|_X=0$ if and only if $x=0$, and $\|Tx\|_Y=0$ if and only if $Tx=0$ (therefore $T(0)=0$). Now, let $x\in X$ be given. Then it is clear that $\|x\|_\beta \geq 0$, and if $x\neq 0$ then $\|x\|_X\neq 0$ and $\|Tx\|_Y\neq 0$, so $\|x\|_\beta=max\{\|x\|_X,\|Tx\|_Y\}\neq 0$. However, if $x=0$, then $\|x\|_X=0$ and $\|Tx\|_Y=0$, therefore $\|x\|_\beta=max\{\|x\|_X,\|Tx\|_Y\}=max\{0,0\}=0$.

Next, as $\|\cdot\|_X$ and $\|\cdot\|_Y$ are norms, we know that given $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, $\|\alpha x\|_X=|\alpha|\|x\|_X$ and $\|T(\alpha x)\|_Y=\|\alpha Tx\|=|\alpha |\|Tx\|$. Therefore

$$\|\alpha x\|_\beta=max\{\|\alpha x\|_X,\|T(\alpha x)\|_Y\}=max\{|\alpha|\|x\|_X,|\alpha|\|Tx\|_Y\}=|\alpha|max\{\|x\|_X,\|Tx\|_Y\}=|\alpha|\|x\|_\beta$$

Finally, as $\|\cdot\|_X$ and $\|\cdot\|_Y$ are norms, we know that given $x,y\in X$ that $\|x+y\|_X\leq \|x\|_X+\|y\|_X$ and $\|T(x+y)\|_Y\leq \|Tx\|_Y+\|Ty\|_Y$. Therefore:

$$\|x+y\|_\beta=max\{\|x+y\|_X,\|T(x+y)\|_Y\}\leq max\{\|x\|_X+\|y\|_X,\|Tx\|_Y+\|Ty\|_Y\}\leq max\{\|x\|_X,\|Tx\|_Y\}+max\{\|y\|_X,\|Ty\|_Y\}=\|x\|_\beta+\|y\|_\beta$$

2) As $\|\cdot\|_X$ and $\|\cdot\|_\beta$ are both norms on a finite dimensional vector space, we know that they are equivalent to each other. Therefore there exists some constant, finite $M$ such that $\|x\|_\beta\leq M\|x\|_X$. Also, it is clear that $\|Tx\|_Y\leq \|x\|_\beta$. Therefore it is clear that $T$ is bounded, and therefore continuous.

Comment: I haven't looked at the detail, but this should work the way you outlined it. There is a big *but* though: It relies on the equivalence of norms on finite dimensional spaces. That is the *hard* bit, and your proof does nothing to change that

Comment: Note that there also is a stronger version of the norm equivalence result that you use. Namely, in a finite-dimensional vector space there is only a single Hausdorff linear topology (the norm topology) and any (non-Hausdorff) linear topology is weaker than that. 

In your case, $\|Tx\|_Y$ is a seminorm, which defines a locally convex topology. So this topology is not greater than the norm topology. Hence both the seminorm and $T$ are continuous.